# Booting problem that shows stripe

Tags: boot, nvidia

I am new here. I have problem with my Ubuntu at booting, and I had restared for many times with no movement/change. Before the problem, I want to change from open source to the Nvidia proprietary driver and it doesn't have movement so I terminated the process. But it showed the driver needs to get reinstall to use it again. And I guess I haven't change the settings into it.

But when I restarted to computer, my Ubuntu startup logo stretched just like when I used the Nvidia driver for the first time but it's not as usual. I am stuck at stripe for a long time.

I am sorry that the picture can't be showed. Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: The symptoms you describe could indicate many problems. The screenshot would not be particularly useful, but contents of system logs, output from `dmesg` could record something that can be investigated. In any case it gets very difficult to debug from here. Is reinstalling the system an option?

Comment: I am not sure to do that, but can I repair it with LiveCD? My files are in there.

Comment: It is possible you could reinstall the system from the installation source *if* you put /home on a separate partition (or wherever your files are). Then you could recreate the root file system and reinstall without losing your files. I don’t know of any automated “repair” type functionality that exists on a LiveCD.